# QGIS save shapefile - problems with attribute table

Tags: qgis, shapefile, attribute-table, export

I added point coordinates of a delimited text file layer with an attribute table containing about 1000 columns.

As soon as I want to save this created layer as a shapefile I get an error that some creation of a certain field failed (reason unkown). When excluding this field there is a problem with another one and so on.

I guess QGIS can´t deal with an attribute table this large or there are some characters in the text that QGIS can´t handle (I´ve already tried to replace underscores with points).

Any other suggestion why this does not work out?

Or maybe other ways to tranform a .csv format with coordinates to .shp ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not QGIS, it's the shapefile that is the limitation.

[Shapefiles can not have more than 255 attributes](http://switchfromshapefile.org/#255attributes).